# How to update _User object after another object has been saved in Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, cloud

I'm trying to keep track of the number of comments made about a user in my application. These comments can be made by other user and of course these other users can't update the User they're commenting about. So i was wondering if there was any way to do this with Cloud code on Parse.

Edit :I'm also looking to update a value called "latestPostTime" that will get the current time of the latest post. any help would be amazing thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can, have a look at `beforeSave` and `afterSave` triggers. For example you can create an `afterSave` trigger for your comments class and then update the user object the comment has been made on/about.

Have a look at the [Cloud Code documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers) for the triggers, that should help to get you started.

If you run into ACL issues, you can enable usage of the master key in a Cloud Code function as well to update the count field of the user object.

Comment: Ok I have looked at the documentation and I still don't know how to access values of the comment and grab the user that the comment was about. Any help would be really appreciated @Björn Kaiser

Comment: The data should be in the request, IIRC, `request.object` is the object being saved aka your comment, you should be able to get the pointer/id of the user the comment was made on from there `request.object.get("nameOfTheField")`